# using hashed passwords in php code

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

I want to put passwords that are in our source-code in a extern file and access them via PHP function.
But I don't want to have them there in clear text so my idea was to hash them.

The question is how I can I decrypt them when they are needed in the application. (there will be no manual password entry)

Or is this the wrong way to solve the problem?

Greetings ant thanks !!

Comment: By definition you can't decrypt a hash. But this does seem a decent scenario to encrypt the password assuming we're talking about credentials used by your app to access external services.

Comment: Hashing is a one way process. Encrypting is a two way process. All you can do is to encrypt your password and store it in a safe location.

Comment: You encrypt a password, saved the encrypted password and match that string with the password (you first have to encrypt again) the user supplies.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think you just described a hashing / hash checking, not encryption.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers but the sever just accepts clear passwords, that means that the passwords must be in clear-form in the code too.
I just want to put them in a variable ($password) but before sending the variable to the server i want to decrypt them from a file where i keep them in encrypted form....

Comment: Are these passwords for users accounts?

Comment: maybe the solution is just to put the password file into a protected folder where just root can read it ? :-)

Comment: the passwords are just for application use but are also used by users sometimes...

Comment: a) you hash passwords b) you **never ever ever** decrypt them. that would completely defeat the purpose (and definition) of hashing. if *you* can decrypt them, an attacker can, *too*, making every password stored in your system insecure by definition.

Answer (score -1):

You can use crypt()  to save the passwords

```
public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === crypt($password, 'hash');
    }
```

[crypt](http://%20public%20function%20validatePassword($password)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20$this-%3Epassword%20===%20crypt($password,%20Yii::$app-%3Eparams['hash']);%20%20%20%20%20%7D)

Comment: Ok,You write that at you question :)